# Is it possible to create nested multiselect custom field?

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, directory, organization

The use-case is a business directory. Businesses sign themselves up and provide info about their operation. There are many types of businesses (NAICS), and the options they need to self-identify as are nested in a multiselect format. Is this re-creatable with CiviCRM?

See image.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible via Custom Fields - this is possible via Tags.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I've looked into it a bit but its not clear to me how to integrate this into a self-signup form. The businesses registering have to be able to set their own tags.

Comment: by 'set' do you mean 'choose out of an existing set' or 'create new tag'? if the former, and you are on Drupal you might find you get better options via webform integration

Comment: We are looking at Drupal and webform integration, yes. We would set up all the codes ahead of time, and we want businesses who are signing up through a webform to be able to self-identify under those codes. They have to be nested though because there are SO many that the list would be a mile long. Plus the structure of these ID codes is an external legal classification system that by nature is nested into categories and subcategories. Does that answer your question?

Comment: we had to do something that might seem similar. educational codes for courses/papers. we did it as a custom table to store all the options, then customise so we could show that data as an autocomplete, and then store that data in a custom field. but it was only one outcome per entity (which were Activities in our case). I don't think in webforms you can display the Tags as a hierarchy if that is what you are after.